# Doing the riemann sum in cylindrical shells using left endpoints?

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

[image]

The picture shows how the method of cylindrical shells is explained using a riemann sum of midpoints, but can we do this sum using left end points or right end points?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant *Riemann* sum

Comment: Yes that is what i mean thank you.